# NodeJS refreshing the database table's data continuously

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, cron

I'm scrapping a data and inserting them into database every day by cron.Job() .
But the database results on server does not refresh itself after inserting some data.

I found 2 answers here. But couldn't understand one and the other was also old.

In code I truncate table firstly, then I am inserting new data. But it shows me old data when I send a request.

In get_pharmacy.js I'm just doing some sorting operations and sending response to user.

Here is my code:

```
var port = 4000;
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var get_pharmacy = require("./routes/get_pharmacy.js");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var cron = require('cron');

app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/get_pharmacy", get_pharmacy);

var job1 = new cron.CronJob({
    cronTime: '55 59 21 * * 1-7', // 00 00 22
    onTick: function() {
        var deleter = require("/home/ahmet/development_nuri/deleter.js");
    },
    start: false,
timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});

var job2 = new cron.CronJob({
    cronTime: '00 00 22 * * 1-7', // 00 00 22
    onTick: function() {
        var istanbul = require("/home/ahmet/development_nuri/scrap.js");
    },
    start: false,
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
job1.start();
job2.start();

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log('UNCAUGHT', err.stack);
});

app.listen(port);
```

get_pharmacy.js (requests comes here)

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "159487aa",
    database: "eczane",
    debug: false
});
var cities = [];

const router = express.Router();

setInterval(function () {
    con.query('SELECT 1');
}, 5000);

function swap(a,b)
{
  var temp=a;

}

function sortMeThender(data)
{

    var array = []
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        for(var x=0;  x<data.length; x++)
        {
            if(data[i]["distance"] < data[x]["distance"])
            {
                var temp=data[x];
                 data[x]=data[i];
                 data[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    array.push(data[0]);
    array.push(data[1]);
    array.push(data[2]);
    array.push(data[3]);
    array.push(data[4]);
    return array;

}

router.route("/")
    .post(function(request, response) {

        var lat = request.body.lat;
        var long = request.body.long;

            con.query("select name,adress,town,city,phone,latitude,longitude from eczane", function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                cities.push(result);
                for (var i = 0; i < cities[0].length; i++) {
                    cities[0][i]["distance"] = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat, long, cities[0][i]["latitude"], cities[0][i]["longitude"]);
                }
                response.send(sortMeThender(cities[0]));
            });

        function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {

            var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
            var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
            var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
            var a =
                Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
            ;
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            var d = R * c; // Distance in km
            return d * 1000;
        }

        function deg2rad(deg) {
            return deg * (Math.PI/180)
        }
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cities variable in the get_pharmacy.js is global. Change it to local (use it inside the post method).